# How to bind a prop value using a function and pass it to another component

Tags: vuejs2

Is it possible to bind a prop to a function?
In my example below I’m trying to get a value from a function in the main App.vue and pass it as a prop to the child component `customComponent`.

e.g. (this example doesn’t work)

#### App.vue

```
import customComponent from ‘./custom-component.vue'
<template>
     <custom-component
        v-bind:myValue="geMyValue()"
      ></custom-component>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "Item",
    methods: {
        getMyValue: function() {
            return 1+3;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

customComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <h3 class="some-custom-layout">custom component</h3>
    <input type="button" @click="sendMyValue()" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: “custom",
    props: ['myValue']
    methods: {
        sendMyValue: function() {
            console.log(this.myValue);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible: https://jsfiddle.net/sbg8g9bk/. Your example wouldn't work because you are calling `geMyValue` in the template, not `getMyValue`

Comment: @thanksd Gr8! Why not put that in an answer so you can get the kudos?

Comment: I voted to close this question, as the root issue was just a typo

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but probably it would be better to use computed properties, if you are going to return value:

```
<template>
     <custom-component
        v-bind:myValue="myValue"
      ></custom-component>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: "Item",
    computed: {
        myValue: function() {
            return 1+3;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html